# How to split the output of a `printenv` shell command?

Tags: regular-expressions, string

Basically, I want to split a *multiline* string at the regular expression that, *in Perl*, would be specified with `\n(?=[^\W\d]\w*=)`.

Note that the Perl regexp features a "zero-width lookahead match" (`(?=...)`), meaning that the substrings that match this part of the regexp will not be "consumed"; they will appear in their corresponding entries in the resulting list.

For example, the string whose printed representation is

```
A=1
B_C_D=
foo
bar
baz
  =whatever=
X_Y_Z=quux
```

would be split into the following three-element list:

```
("A=1" "B_C_D=\nfoo\nbar\nbaz\n  =whatever=" "X_Y_Z=quux\n")
```

Even though Elisp regexps do not support lookahead/lookbehind expressions, this sort of splitting problem (in which part or all of each matching substring is not consumed) is common enough that I hope there are some other standard ways to solve it in Elisp.

Moreover, the ultimate goal here is to split the output of the shell command

```
/usr/bin/zsh -ilc 'printenv' 2>/dev/null
```

so that each element of the result would correspond to one "setting" of an environment variable<sup>1</sup>.  So I also figure that Elisp may possibly have functions that facilitate the handling of this special case<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The desired result is *conceptually similar* to value of the variable `process-environment`, but in general it is *not* be identical to it.  Also, the side-effects associated with setting and updating `process-environment` do *not* enter into my problem.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> Unfortunately, it appears that `process-environment` is initialized in C-code, so whatever functions do that are not available in Elisp.</sup>

Comment: If you are happy about patching the emacs source you could try this: https://github.com/gamesun/emacs-regex-lookaround  But note that it is written against 24.2 so may need modifying for more recent versions

Answer (score 4):

This might not be quite the answer you want, but use `printenv -0` instead. This puts a `NUL` between each "line" of output, which in this case will be between each var=value pair:

```
TMUX_PANE=%0^@test=foo
bar
baz
^@SHLVL=2
```

Parsing that will be much easier.

Code:

```
(split-string (shell-command-to-string "printenv -0") "\0" t)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think db48x has the right answer for your underlying problem (without the -0 argument, printenv's output is ambiguous in case one of your env vars contains `...\nfoo=bar`).

But as for how to do it in Elisp, I'd do it as follows:

```
(defun parse-foo (str)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert str)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let ((start (point))
          (strs ()))
    (while (re-search-forward "\n\\w+=" nil 'move)
      (push (buffer-substring start (match-beginning 0)) strs)
      (setq start (1+ (match-beginning 0))))
    (cons (buffer-substring start (point)) strs)))
```